# Grid column not showing in admin grid on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, column

I have created a custom module for backend with 3 columns like this:

1. PostAction.php located in **vendor\namespace\Ui\Component\Listing\Column**

   class PostActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
   {

   ```
   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
       {
           if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
               foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                   if (isset($item['id'])) {
                       $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                           'edit' => [
                               'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                   static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                   [
                                       'id' => $item['id']
                                   ]
                               ),
                               'label' => __('Edit')
                           ],
                           'delete' => [
                               'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                   static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                                   [
                                       'id' => $item['id']
                                   ]
                               ),
                               'label' => __('Delete'),
                               'confirm' => [
                                   'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.name }"'),
                                   'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete the Post "${ $.$data.name }" ?')
                               ]
                           ]
                       ];
                   }
               }
           }
           return $dataSource;
       }
   ```

   }

my UI commpoents where i added the columns:

```
<column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email" class="vendor\namespace\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

In my admin i see only 2 colums: the column with **ID** and **Name**, but the column with **email** doesn't appear at all.
I have tried to add the column in manny ways but no success.
I have tried like this also:

```
<column name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Does anyone know what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: try using `<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>`  and remove class from it. And why is uicomponent form file and the column you are showing are different. As I see you have added email column email as action column.

Comment: i have tried but no success

Answer (score 2):

I was not careful and I forgot about the "column" option and my column was not selected.

Maybe this will help someone.

[image]